# Self - complementary graphs with up to 7 vertices

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

How could I find all the self complementary graphs with 7 vertices at most? Is there an algorithm that produces self-complementary graphs?

Comment: A self complementary graph must be isomorphic to its complement, so how many edges must it have? (Leaning towards why there aren't any self complementary graphs with seven vertices).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only one's you can find are:
1 vertix,
4 vertices: 2-2-1-1 degrees,
5 vertices: 3-2-2-2-1 , 2-2-2-2-2
For 2,3,6,7 vertices, graphs are not self-complementary as if you devide their edges with 2, the number you get is odd.

Comment: why is it not ok , the division by 2 to be an odd number?

Comment: because you need each one of the complementary graphs to have the same number of edges as the other. If the number cannot be devided by two, you can't do that.

Comment: that is because , the "empty" edges (the edges missing that would make the graph complete) will be less than the full edges , so the complementary

Answer (score 0):

As Amy says, you need the number of edges of $G$ to be half the number of possible edges, i.e. $n(n-1)/4$. So this has to be an integer, which requires $n\equiv 0,1\pmod 4$.

For $n=4$ your degree sequence has to add up to $6$, and for $n=5$ to $10$. It has to be symmetrical - there are the same number of degrees $k$ as $n-1-k$ for each $k$. Since you can't have both a vertex connected to everythin and one connected to nothing, you can't have degrees $0$ or $n-1$.

For $n=5$ this gives one possible sequence $2,2,1,1$ and it's easy to see there is only one graph with this sequence. For $n=5$ the options are $2,2,2,2,2$ or $3,2,2,2,1$ or $3,3,2,1,1$. The first and third of these both have exactly one possible graph. However, the sequence $3,2,2,2,1$ can't give a self-complementary graph. The two vertices of high and low degree swap over when we take the complement, and this means if they are adjacent in $G$ they are non-adjacent in $\overline{G}$.

Comment: why can't 3 , 2 , 2 , 1 give a self complementary graph?

Comment: It would have 4 edges, so its complement would have 2.